# Java: DatagramSocket and proxy (firewall)

Tags: java, proxy, udp

It may be that I'm not understanding the UDP protocol...

I'm trying to receive data from a server using the UDP protocol, but I'm sitting behind a firewall.  The URLConnection constructor can take an instance of Proxy (as well as a way to set up user name and password of such a proxy server).

How do I connect through a proxy server using the UDP protocol (DatagramSocket)?

Best regards,
TX

Comment: The Socket class http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html allows to use proxy http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html

Comment: This link (http://www.interhack.net/projects/deschall/archive/199705/0489.html) is a class that sends datagrams with Proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Proxy servers support the HTTP protocol which is TCP based, so you don't have to do anything with the proxy server to do this.

To pass UDP over a proxy server, you need a proxy which supports UDP.  I don't know of any proxy server which supports this so you may have to write one yourself. It is worth noting that UDP is a connectionless protocol which means you have have to authenticate every packet.

Answer (score 0):

SOCKS5, which is an extension of SOCKS4, includes support for UDP in addition to authentication. One implementation of a SOCKS5 Server written in Java is JSOCKS. You can check this project out at http://jsocks.sourceforge.net/.

Refer to RFC 1928 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) for more information on SOCKS5.